# How do I send an array of objects from one Activity to another?

Tags: android, class, bundle

I have a class like:

```
Class persona implements Serializable {

    int age;
    String name;

}
```

And my first Activity fill an array:

```
persona[] p;
```

Then, I need this info in another Activity. **How I can send it?**

I try to make:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("persona", p);
```

But I Can't.

Comment: may be this is an bug see this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3847

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK the is no method that put a serializable array into bundle any way here is a solution to use that uses parcel

change you class to this

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class persona implements Parcelable {

    int age;
    String name;

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<persona> CREATOR = new Creator<persona>() {

        @Override
        public persona[] newArray(int size) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new persona[size];
        }

        @Override
        public persona createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new persona(source);
        }
    };

    public persona(Parcel in) {
        super();
        age = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
    }

    public persona() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(age);
        dest.writeString(name);

    }
}
```

then you can send the array like this

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();

b.putParcelableArray("persona", p);
```

btw using Parcelable instead of Serializable is more efficient in Android

Comment: but this is second solution for problem.point is how we pass Array of Custom Class Objects to other class when class is `implements Serializable` . if you have any solution on same way as 
@user1782922 is doing then it's more helpful for all.thanks

Answer (score 1):

You class will need to implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Then, you can send it in a bundle by using the [`Bundle.putParcelableArray()`-method.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArray%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%5B%5D%29)

Also, a general advice: Class names should **always** start uppercase